# \newenvironment text exceeds the text width

Tags: line-breaking, environments

I set up a `\newenvironment`, some texts in this environment exceed the text width, but this doesn't happen always. The following is the `\newenvironment` setup

```
% is used for parameters within a detailed function description
\newenvironment{DoxyParamCaption}{%
   \renewcommand{\item}[2][]{##1 {\em ##2}}%
}{%
}

\subsubsection[{j1939\_\-initialize\_\-stack}]{\setlength{\rightskip}%
{0pt   plus 5cm}void j1939\_\-initialize\_\-stack (
\begin{DoxyParamCaption}
\item[{{\bf j1939\_\-stack\_\-id\_\-t}}]{stack\_\-id, }
\item[{{\bf ProtocolRXTablePtr}}]{rx\_\-table\_\-ptr, }
\item[{{\bf J1939TransmitMessagePtr}}]{tx\_\-table\_\-ptr, }
\item[{{\bf uint16}}]{tx\_\-table\_\-size, }
\item[{{\bf uchar8} $\ast$}]{rx\_\-buff, }
\item[{{\bf uint16}}]{rx\_\-buff\_\-size}
\end{DoxyParamCaption}
)}}
```

The result will be like as follows

[image]

As you can see, the function's head goes into the right margin of the paper. But some other examples works fine. See another one in the same environment as follows

[image]

I don't why this happens. Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you very very much.

Comment: You shouldn't use the old LaTeX2.0 style formatting macros like `\bf` or `\it` any longer. Use `bfseries` instead. See e.g. [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you explicitly state the hyphenations of the variables (via `\-`), you leave the variable types (typeset using `{\bf ...}`) as is. This is a problem, since LaTeX does not know where these "words" need to be hyphenated at the end of a line. This is also evident from LaTeX's attempt to hyphenate `DataWidth` as `DataW\-idth` in your second example; something that is obviously wrong.

One solution might be impose a `\raggedright` formatting in the `\subsubsection{...}` definition that would allow words to be wrapped (instead of hyphenated) at the end of `\linewidth`:

```
\subsubsection[{j1939\_\-initialize\_\-stack}]{\raggedright%
  void j1939\_\-initialize\_\-stack (
  \begin{DoxyParamCaption}
    \item[{{\bf j1939\_\-stack\_\-id\_\-t}}]{stack\_\-id, }
    \item[{{\bf ProtocolRXTablePtr}}]{rx\_\-table\_\-ptr, }
    \item[{{\bf J1939TransmitMessagePtr}}]{tx\_\-table\_\-ptr, }
    \item[{{\bf uint16}}]{tx\_\-table\_\-size, }
    \item[{{\bf uchar8} $\ast$}]{rx\_\-buff, }
    \item[{{\bf uint16}}]{rx\_\-buff\_\-size}
  \end{DoxyParamCaption}
)}
```

However, this actually makes the use of manual hyphenation unnecessary. Regardless, some cleanup is also encouraged in the code:

- As suggested by [`l2tabu`](http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf), the use of `{\bf ...}` is considered obsolete. Rather use `\textbf{...}` for local font changes, or `{\bfseries ...}` for global font changes.
- There's no need for double-nesting the descriptor field of `\item[...]`. It would suffice to have `\item[\textbf{uint16}]{rx\_\-buff\_\-size}`.
- **Edit:** <strike>The redefinition of `\item` does not require using `##1` and `##2`; so change it to `#1` and `#2`. Not sure whether this is possible, since your document may contain other uses and/or redefinitions, so you're keeping it this way for consistency.</strike>
- You could include the **boldface** font change for the variable type in the redefinition of `\item`.

Using the above suggestions your code example could be simplified to

```
% is used for parameters within a detailed function description
\newenvironment{DoxyParamCaption}{%
   \renewcommand{\item}[2][]{\textbf{##1} {\normalfont\em ##2}}%
}{%
}

\subsubsection[j1939\_initialize\_stack]{\raggedright%
  void j1939\_initialize\_stack (
  \begin{DoxyParamCaption}
    \item[j1939\_stack\_id\_t]{stack\_id, }
    \item[ProtocolRXTablePtr]{rx\_table\_ptr, }
    \item[J1939TransmitMessagePtr]{tx\_table\_ptr, }
    \item[uint16]{tx\_table\_size, }
    \item[uchar8 $\ast$]{rx\_buff, }
    \item[uint16]{rx\_buff\_size}
  \end{DoxyParamCaption})}
```

which is a little easier to read. Since the scope/extent of the use is not clearly specified, defining a more solid definition of `\subsubsection` to automatically perform a `\raggedright` justification via (say) [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) was not implemented.

Comment: For defining \subsubsection via titlesec package, using \filright works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The MWE example and method you are trying to use to format text is very complicated and will lead to a lot of errors while you typing in the information.

Firstly, I would use the `underscore` package to provide the underscores (eliminating `\_`).
If words are mixed with non-characters, TeX will not hyphenate words such as,

```
   J1939TransmitMessagePtr
```

is not hyphenated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{underscore}
\makeatletter
 \def\pointer#1{\@tfor\next:=#1\do{\next\-}}
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
\hsize1in
\subsubsection[{j1939_initialize_stack}]{%
    stack_id, {\bf  J1939Transmit\-MessagePtr} 
 }
 % autohyphenate pointer
 \pointer{J1939TransmitMessagePtr}
\end{document}
```

In the example I have left `\bf` as you did to demonstrate that it is not the cause of the error. You should change it to `\bfseries'`.

My own preference is to define individual macros as I have done for `pointer`, introduce the optional hyphen or replace `\-` with `hskip0pt` if you don't want the hyphen to show up, as it is sometimes confusing in computer code.